# Linq-to-XML get elements with namespace

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

i am using linq-to-xml to search elements.

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                    var ns = doc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
                    var result = (from u in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("MyElement", ns))
```

i need to get rid of using XName.Get whenever i try to find an element in xml. how can i set a default namespace to XDocument so that it will not bother when searching.

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way of ignoring default namespaces, if you really want to do that:

```
        XDocument doc;
        using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader("input.xml"))
        {
            xr.Namespaces = false;
            doc = XDocument.Load(xr);
        }
        foreach (XElement bar in doc.Descendants("bar"))
```

But I would suggest to accept the existence and importance of namespaces in XML and use the XName and XNamespace objects LINQ to XML provides to work with them.

Comment: yes i agree with the importance of namespace but in my case my xml document elements belong to a single namespace i already know. so i really don't need to pass it again and again while searching elements.

Answer (score 4):

> i need to get rid of using XName.Get whenever i try to find an element in xml. how can i set a default namespace to XDocument so that it will not bother when searching.

You can't - but there are two other options:

- Use the `+(XNamespace, string)` operator:

  ```
  doc.Descendants(ns + "MyElement")
  ```
- Just create the `XName` values once, then refer to them in your query, e.g.

  ```
  XName myElementName = ns + "MyElement";
  ...
  doc.Descendants(myElementName);
  ```

Ideally, you wouldn't create the namespace dynamically anyway - don't you *know* the namespace you should be looking in? If you do, you can create private static readonly fields with the appropriate `XName` values.

Comment: so there is no way to say all elements in this node belongs to this namespace and that will allow me to just search elements by name right?

Comment: @Shoaib Shaikh: You only ever search by `XName`, not by string. When you create an `XName` by converting from string, that creates an `XName` with no namespace.

Comment: You could remove the namespace from the text of the xml before working with it as an XDocument.

Comment: You can use element.Name.LocalName in your search.

Comment: @ImaDirtyTroll: But why would you do that rather than just specifying the namespace? (Which is what I'd do when using MSBuild, too...) In most cases, you really *don't* want to end up with elements which are in the wrong namespace but happen to be in the document.

Comment: Sorry I was responding to Eric's comment.

I was also responding to your comment 'You only ever search by XName, not by string', which is not strictly true.  (The thread is a little confused.) The OP seems to mostly want to work around namespaces altogether.

Comment: @ImaDirtyTroll: I guess I should have clarified: "The methods which take an element or attribute name to find only have XName parameters, not string".

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do:

```
doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
var ns = doc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
var result = from u in doc.Descendants.Elements(ns+"MyElement").Select(c=>c.Value);
```

Comment: again this will require ns to be concatenated and make the code a little obscure. can't we avoid ns?

Comment: your query should be as follows:
var result = from u in doc.Descendants().Elements(ns + "MyElement") select u;

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the LocalName, which uglifies the LINQ, but gets the job done.  (in this case getting attributes from an MSBuild project file).

```
var imports = from i in doc.Root.Elements()
              where i.Name.LocalName == "Import"
              from p in i.Attributes()
              where p.Name.LocalName == "Project"
              select p.Value;
```

The thing I like about doing it this way is that it leaves the XML in its original form, and yet it suggests to others that something funny is going on.  Putting 'LocalName' in the LINQ expression is sort of a self-documenting hack.

Turning off namespaces in the XmlTextReader is easily overlooked if the code gets separated.

Answer (score 0):

Create extension methods:

```
        public static XElement ElementInCurrentNamespace(this XElement element, string elementName)
        {
            return element
                .Element(element.Name.Namespace.GetName(elementName));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsInCurrentNamespace(this XElement element, string elementName)
        {
            return element
                .Elements(element.Name.Namespace.GetName(elementName));
        }
```

- On the first time of accessing an element with namespace, use `.Element` or `.Elements` method with namespace, such as `element.Element(namespace.GetName("foo"))`.
- Afterwards (as long as descendant elements have the same namespace) use the above extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but here is my thought:

Elements.xml root element contains a namespace attribute. The following code ignores the namespace.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Elements.xml");

            if (doc.Root != null)
                foreach (XElement xElement in doc.Root.Elements())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xElement);
                }
```